# html template for profile box

Tags: html, css, responsive

I want create profile box like below picture

[image]

and use this item in grid layout with three column using bootstrap 3, but user picture it is not fully responsive and cut like this:

[image]

My HTML and css code snippet is as follow:

```css
.ProfileItem {
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
.ProfileImg {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    width: 35%;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.ProfileDes {
    padding: 5px 18px 0px 10px !important;
    position: relative;
    right: 35%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 65%;
}
.imageContain {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.imageContain img {
    width: 100%;
}
.profileTitle {
    color: #5a5a5a;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.profileInfo {
    color: #5a5a5a;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="ProfileItem">
    <div class="ProfileImg">
        <div class="imageContain"><img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt=""></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ProfileDes">
        <a class="profileTitle" href="" title="">User Fullname</a>
        <div class="profileInfo">Description 1</div>
        <div class="profileInfo">Description 2</div>
        <div class="profileInfo">Description 3</div>
        <div class="profileInfo">Description 4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: How about using the `min-height` css property to ensure that there's minimum space for picture height? The other way can be to dynamically adjust the image size using JS.

Comment: the main problem is "imageContain" class. how to force "imageContain" class be full square or full circle in every device-width  ???

Answer (score 0):

```
.imageContain {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 40%;
  height: auto;
}
```

> You only need to add width and height to class 'imageContain'. You need to change width according to your image dimensions.

Comment: height: 100%;  or  bottom:0; solve my problem temporary . how to force "imageContain" class be full square or full circle in every device-width ???

Comment: try it by giving height:auto.